# Get date create and last modify of media file

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to convert CTime to PROPVARIANT on MFC, who can show me how do i get the date created, last modified of a music file and store with PROVARIANT data type? Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create and Modify date are not stored IN the file. They are stored in the file System and you can read it with [CFile::GetStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fa0hc0ht.aspx)
2. A PROPVARIANT isn't great different from a VARIANT. Internally it also supports the type VT_DATE. This is a double representing the date and time. You can easily use COleDateTime to convert a date also from CTime. [COleDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/38wh24td.aspx) is an easy date/time holder with powerful Features I use it always.

Comment: COleDateTime saves time and mental health. COleDateTime is your friend.

Comment: Thank you so much, i have resolved by using FileTimeToSystemTime(..) and InitPropVariantFromFileTime()